# How to define iptables rule to add all transport to a given interface to nfqueue

Tags: iptables, linux-networking

Running on Ubuntu.
I have machine 1 < - > machine 2  < - > machine 3.
I dont know machine 1 or machine 3 ip. It can be any ip.
machine 1 send packet to machine 3 and machine 3 send packet to machine 1.

Machine 2 is used as a bridge:

```
ifconfig eth0 0.0.0.0
ifconfig eth2 0.0.0.0
brctl addbr br0
brctl addif br0 eth0 eth2
ifconfig br0 up
```

i want to have an iptable rule in machine 2 that will add all traffic that come to eth0 to nfqueue1 and all traffic that come to eth2 to nefqueue2.

Now i have the following rule:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 0
```

which is not good to me because i want to distinguish between traffic that come from machine 3 to traffic that come from machine 1, so i want to have 2 rule.

Add -i eth0 to the rule doesn’t help.

Comment: Can you just add a `-s <source ip>` specifier?

Comment: No . All trafic allowed but i need to distinguish between traffic from machine 1 to machine 3

Comment: Right, and I'm suggesting that you use the source ip address to distinguish machine 1 from machine 3 (I'm not suggesting blocking traffic).  You would need *two* rules in your `FORWARD` chain instead of 1...

Comment: The ip of the machines is not known its group of machines.

Comment: Ah, that wasn't clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you're operating a bridge, you need to use `-m physdev`

for usage, run `iptables -m physdev -h` - if you compile your own kernel, you may need to add this module.

Comment: 10x i will test it tommorow. Why -i interfacename dosnt work ?

Comment: because the incoming interface is considered to be the bridge interface (`br0`), not the bridge port.

Comment: iptables -A FORWARD -m physdev --physdev-in eth0 .... work!!!! great!!!